# define string at compiler options

Tags: c++, vxworks, wind-river-workbench

Using Tornado 2.2.1 GNU

at C/C++ compiler options I'm trying to define string as follow:
-DHELLO="Hello" and it doesn't work (it also failed for -DHELLO=\"Hello\" and for -DHELLO=\\"Hello\\" which works in other platforms)
define value -DVALUE=12 works without issue.

does anybody know to proper way to define string in Tornado?

Comment: have you tried `-DHELLO="\"hello\""`

Comment: @Amadeus: Don't you mean `-DHELLO="\"hello\""`?  (In other words, escape the inner quotes)

Comment: It .. "doesn't work"? What does that mean?

Comment: @yeah, I was correcting it at same time you warn me

Comment: Thanks @Amadeus escaping the inner quotes solved the problem -DHELLO="\"hello\""

Answer (score 3):

The problem with such a macro is, that it normally isn't a string (in the C/C++ sense), just a preprocessor symbol. With numbers it works indeed, because preprocessor number can be used in C/C++ as is, but with string symbols, if you want to convert them to C/C++ strings (besides adding the escaped quotes) you need to "stringize" them.

So, this should work (without extra escaped quotes):

```
#define _STRINGIZE(x) #x
#define STRINGIZE(x) _STRINGIZE(x)

string s = STRINGIZE(HELLO)
```

(note the **double expansion** to get the **value** of the macro stringized, i.e. "Hello", instead of the macro name itself, i.e. "HELLO")